# how to disable selectlistitem in kendogrid conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've kendogrid which has a field that allow user to choose the status of the apartment, I'd like to check if value =3 at grid data bound then disable cell from editing.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ApartmentModel>()
  .Name("UnitsGrid")
  .Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.ForeignKey(o => o.Status, 
              new List<SelectListItem>() { 
              new SelectListItem() { Text =  "Not Reserved", Value = "1", Selected = true }, 
              new SelectListItem() { Text = "Reserved", Value = "2" },
              new SelectListItem() { Text =  "Contracted", Value = "3" } }, "Value", "Text")
```

At grid databound event

```
function GridDataBound(data) {

        var grid = $("#UnitsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        debugger;
        var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();
        for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
            var gridItem = gridData[i];
            if (gridItem.Status == 3) { //Condition
                grid.table.find("[name=Status_input]").hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a [column template](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html-helpers/data-management/grid/faq#how-do-i-have-conditional-logic-in-a-column-client-template?) is a better choice for this scenario. Something like:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Status).Template( @<text>
    @if(@item.Status == 3){
        // Display editable dropdown list
    } else {
       // Just show the value or a message
       "Contracted"
    }
    </text>
);
```